# eGIT and Eclipse : how to set a file to be ignored with GUI interactivity

Tags: eclipse, egit

I know , Its possible as command line.

Can we do this also in the GUI ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on any file in an eGit-managed project and choose **Ignore...** from the context menu.